# clang llvm intermidiate representation for debug information

Tags: c++, inheritance, llvm, clang

Hello I have following c++ code

```
class classBase
{
public:
    int get1(){return 1;}
    int get2(){return 2;}
};
class classDer:public classBase
{
public:
    int get1(){return 1;}
};
```

int f()
{
    classDer x;
    return x.get1();
}

I use following `clangExample.cpp -S -emit-llvm -o -` command and get

```
; ModuleID = 'C:\clangParam\clangExample.cpp'
target datalayout = "e-p:32:32:32-i1:8:8-i8:8:8-i16:16:16-i32:32:32-i64:64:64-f32:32:32-f64:64:64-f80:128:128-v64:64:64-v128:128:128-a0:0:64-f80:32:32-n8:16:32"
target triple = "i686-pc-win32"

%class.classDer = type { i8 }

define i32 @_Z1fv() {
entry:
  %x = alloca %class.classDer, align 1
  %call = call i32 @_ZN8classDer4get1Ev(%class.classDer* %x)
  ret i32 %call
}

define linkonce_odr i32 @_ZN8classDer4get1Ev(%class.classDer* %this) nounwind align 2 {
entry:
  %this.addr = alloca %class.classDer*, align 4
  store %class.classDer* %this, %class.classDer** %this.addr, align 4
  %this1 = load %class.classDer** %this.addr
  ret i32 1
}
```

why there is no reference to the base class?(going over clang code for type generation I got the feeling that the base class type should be referenced.

**Update**
It makes sense 
But if I use Template definition

```
template<class T>
class classTemplate
{
public:
    T getMax(T in1,T in2){if(in2 > in1) return in2;return in1;}
};

int f()
{
    classTemplate<int> x;
    return x.getMax(3,4);
}
```

I get clang output

```
C:\Windows\system32>clang C:\clangParam\clangExample.cpp -S -emit-llvm -o -
; ModuleID = 'C:\clangParam\clangExample.cpp'
target datalayout = "e-p:32:32:32-i1:8:8-i8:8:8-i16:16:16-i32:32:32-i64:64:64-f32:32:32-f64:64:64-f80:128:128-v64:64:64-v128:128:128-a0:0:64-f80:32:32-n8:16:32"
target triple = "i686-pc-win32"

%class.classTemplate = type { i8 }

define i32 @_Z1fv() {
entry:
  %x = alloca %class.classTemplate, align 1
  %call = call i32 @_ZN13classTemplateIiE6getMaxEii(%class.classTemplate* %x, i32 3, i32 4)
  ret i32 %call
}

define linkonce_odr i32 @_ZN13classTemplateIiE6getMaxEii(%class.classTemplate* %this, i32 %in1, i32 %in2) nounwind align 2 {
entry:
  %retval = alloca i32, align 4
  %this.addr = alloca %class.classTemplate*, align 4
  %in1.addr = alloca i32, align 4
  %in2.addr = alloca i32, align 4
  store %class.classTemplate* %this, %class.classTemplate** %this.addr, align 4
  store i32 %in1, i32* %in1.addr, align 4
  store i32 %in2, i32* %in2.addr, align 4
  %this1 = load %class.classTemplate** %this.addr
  %tmp = load i32* %in2.addr, align 4
  %tmp2 = load i32* %in1.addr, align 4
  %cmp = icmp sgt i32 %tmp, %tmp2
  br i1 %cmp, label %if.then, label %if.end

if.then:                                          ; preds = %entry
  %tmp3 = load i32* %in2.addr, align 4
  store i32 %tmp3, i32* %retval
  br label %return

if.end:                                           ; preds = %entry
  %tmp4 = load i32* %in1.addr, align 4
  store i32 %tmp4, i32* %retval
  br label %return

return:                                           ; preds = %if.end, %if.then
  %0 = load i32* %retval
  ret i32 %0
}
```

There is again no reference to template class though I initialize it.

Comment: I think only function f() is visible outside the module, and since it only references your derived class only that makes it down to IR. But it's weird no constructor for classDer is visible. Maybe dev list for clang would be better for this question?

Comment: But get2() function could be called from derived class and it is defined in base class only.What is dev list for clang ?My goal is to run clang in such a way that it will produce maximal debug information.

Comment: http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/mailman/listinfo/cfe-dev probably the best source on clang information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it is not exported and not even compiled is because functions inside class-declarations are inlined. That means they are only known and compiled inside that particular codefile.

If you would put the class-declaration into a headerfile each .cpp-file would compile the code for the get1() and get2() functions seperately (so it would be present twice in the final executable).

ClassBase::get1() and ClassBase::get2() are never referenced, and so they are left out.
The same applies for the possibility of class-overloading: The compiler knows, that there is no derivative of any of the classes, because he sees all there could possibly be.

Comment: this of course doesn't explain how to make clang compile the code and insert debug information for it. however, it wouldn't be useful anyways because the code would never be reached.

Comment: please see the update thank you.Is there any way to force clang to compile the code in such a way that the debug information will be inserted  for it.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you expect debug information without passing `-g`? This outputs a lot of metadata nodes:

```
// clang++ -g3 -S -emit-llvm main1.cpp
// ...

!0 = metadata !{i32 589841, i32 0, i32 4, metadata !"main1.cpp", metadata !"/home/js/cpp", metadata !"clang version 3.0 (trunk 134121)", i1 true, i1 false, metadata !"", i32 0} ; [ DW_TAG_compile_unit ]
!1 = metadata !{i32 589870, i32 0, metadata !2, metadata !"f", metadata !"f", metadata !"_Z1fv", metadata !2, i32 16, metadata !3, i1 false, i1 true, i32 0, i32 0, i32 0, i32 256, i1 false, i32 ()* @_Z1fv, null, null} ; [ DW_TAG_subprogram ]
!2 = metadata !{i32 589865, metadata !"main1.cpp", metadata !"/home/js/cpp", metadata !0} ; [ DW_TAG_file_type ]
!3 = metadata !{i32 589845, metadata !2, metadata !"", metadata !2, i32 0, i64 0, i64 0, i32 0, i32 0, i32 0, metadata !4, i32 0, i32 0} ; [ DW_TAG_subroutine_type ]
!4 = metadata !{metadata !5}
!5 = metadata !{i32 589860, metadata !0, metadata !"int", null, i32 0, i64 32, i64 32, i64 0, i32 0, i32 5} ; [ DW_TAG_base_type ]
!6 = metadata !{i32 589870, i32 0, metadata !7, metadata !"get1", metadata !"get1", metadata !"_ZN9classBase4get1Ev", metadata !2, i32 5, metadata !10, i1 false, i1 false, i32 0, i32 0, null, i32 256, i1 false, null, null} ; [ DW_TAG_subprogram ]
!7 = metadata !{i32 589826, metadata !0, metadata !"classBase", metadata !2, i32 2, i64 8, i64 8, i32 0, i32 0, null, metadata !8, i32 0, null, null} ; [ DW_TAG_class_type ]
!8 = metadata !{metadata !6, metadata !9, metadata !13}
!9 = metadata !{i32 589870, i32 0, metadata !7, metadata !"get2", metadata !"get2", metadata !"_ZN9classBase4get2Ev", metadata !2, i32 6, metadata !10, i1 false, i1 false, i32 0, i32 0, null, i32 256, i1 false, null, null} ; [ DW_TAG_subprogram ]
!10 = metadata !{i32 589845, metadata !2, metadata !"", metadata !2, i32 0, i64 0, i64 0, i32 0, i32 0, i32 0, metadata !11, i32 0, i32 0} ; [ DW_TAG_subroutine_type ]
!11 = metadata !{metadata !5, metadata !12}
!12 = metadata !{i32 589839, metadata !0, metadata !"", i32 0, i32 0, i64 32, i64 32, i64 0, i32 64, metadata !7} ; [ DW_TAG_pointer_type ]
!13 = metadata !{i32 589870, i32 0, metadata !7, metadata !"classBase", metadata !"classBase", metadata !"", metadata !2, i32 2, metadata !14, i1 false, i1 false, i32 0, i32 0, null, i32 320, i1 false, null, null} ; [ DW_TAG_subprogram ]
!14 = metadata !{i32 589845, metadata !2, metadata !"", metadata !2, i32 0, i64 0, i64 0, i32 0, i32 0, i32 0, metadata !15, i32 0, i32 0} ; [ DW_TAG_subroutine_type ]
!15 = metadata !{null, metadata !12}
!16 = metadata !{i32 589870, i32 0, metadata !17, metadata !"get1", metadata !"get1", metadata !"_ZN8classDer4get1Ev", metadata !2, i32 11, metadata !24, i1 false, i1 false, i32 0, i32 0, null, i32 256, i1 false, null, null} ; [ DW_TAG_subprogram ]
!17 = metadata !{i32 589826, metadata !0, metadata !"classDer", metadata !2, i32 8, i64 8, i64 8, i32 0, i32 0, null, metadata !18, i32 0, null, null} ; [ DW_TAG_class_type ]
!18 = metadata !{metadata !19, metadata !16, metadata !20}
!19 = metadata !{i32 589852, metadata !17, null, metadata !2, i32 0, i64 0, i64 0, i64 0, i32 0, metadata !7} ; [ DW_TAG_inheritance ]
!20 = metadata !{i32 589870, i32 0, metadata !17, metadata !"classDer", metadata !"classDer", metadata !"", metadata !2, i32 8, metadata !21, i1 false, i1 false, i32 0, i32 0, null, i32 320, i1 false, null, null} ; [ DW_TAG_subprogram ]
!21 = metadata !{i32 589845, metadata !2, metadata !"", metadata !2, i32 0, i64 0, i64 0, i32 0, i32 0, i32 0, metadata !22, i32 0, i32 0} ; [ DW_TAG_subroutine_type ]
!22 = metadata !{null, metadata !23}
!23 = metadata !{i32 589839, metadata !0, metadata !"", i32 0, i32 0, i64 32, i64 32, i64 0, i32 64, metadata !17} ; [ DW_TAG_pointer_type ]
!24 = metadata !{i32 589845, metadata !2, metadata !"", metadata !2, i32 0, i64 0, i64 0, i32 0, i32 0, i32 0, metadata !25, i32 0, i32 0} ; [ DW_TAG_subroutine_type ]
!25 = metadata !{metadata !5, metadata !23}
!26 = metadata !{i32 589870, i32 0, metadata !0, metadata !"get1", metadata !"get1", metadata !"_ZN8classDer4get1Ev", metadata !2, i32 11, metadata !24, i1 false, i1 true, i32 0, i32 0, i32 0, i32 256, i1 false, i32 (%class.classDer*)* @_ZN8classDer4get1Ev, null, metadata !16} ; [ DW_TAG_subprogram ]
!27 = metadata !{i32 590080, metadata !28, metadata !"x", metadata !2, i32 17, metadata !17, i32 0} ; [ DW_TAG_auto_variable ]
!28 = metadata !{i32 589835, metadata !1, i32 16, i32 1, metadata !2, i32 0} ; [ DW_TAG_lexical_block ]
!29 = metadata !{i32 17, i32 14, metadata !28, null}
!30 = metadata !{i32 18, i32 5, metadata !28, null}
!31 = metadata !{i32 590081, metadata !26, metadata !"this", metadata !2, i32 16777227, metadata !23, i32 64} ; [ DW_TAG_arg_variable ]
!32 = metadata !{i32 11, i32 9, metadata !26, null}
!33 = metadata !{i32 11, i32 16, metadata !34, null}
!34 = metadata !{i32 589835, metadata !26, i32 11, i32 15, metadata !2, i32 1} ; [ DW_TAG_lexical_block ]
```

Looking for the class-type tags, you find

```
!7 = metadata !{i32 589826, metadata !0, metadata !"classBase", metadata !2, i32 2, i64 8, i64 8, i32 0, i32 0, null, metadata !8, i32 0, null, null} ; [ DW_TAG_class_type ]
!17 = metadata !{i32 589826, metadata !0, metadata !"classDer", metadata !2, i32 8, i64 8, i64 8, i32 0, i32 0, null, metadata !18, i32 0, null, null} ; [ DW_TAG_class_type ]
```

Comment: Thank you.It is very useful for me.But in clang --help I didn`t find the g3 option.Do you know some manual that explains all the options.

Comment: @Yakov `clang -cc1 --help` will show you all fancy options. Many GCC options work though, as does `-g`.